# New to python struggling with append

Tags: python, append

Hey I've looked around but can't seem to find an answer. I am looking to identify and print the number of files in a list & their names, but keeping running into a an error. I am new to python so I am quite sure I got something wrong and apologize if this is a stupid question. Below is the code I have so far

```
import os
folderpath = "C:\Users\Michaelf\Desktop\GEOG M173\LabData"
filelist = os.listdir(folderpath)
print filelist
Counter_Shapefiles = 0
Names_of_Shapefiles = 0

for the_file_name in filelist:
     File_Extension = the_file_name[-4:]
     if "file_Extension == .shp":
         Counter_Shapefiles= Counter_Shapefiles + 1
         Names_of_Shapefiles.append
```

Comment: What is the error? First of all append is a function which takes an argument

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "an error".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michaelf\Desktop\GEOG M173\week_2_Lab.py", line 30, in <module>
    Names_of_Shapefiles.append
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Sorry I am not very well versed in python, but will make sure to include error in future posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use append you need a list not an int so

```
Name_of_Shapefiles = 0
```

should be

```
Name_of_Shapefiles = []
```

Second, the syntax for append is `Names_of_Shapefiles.append(the_file_name)`

Comment: Thanks I followed your corrections and it corrected the errors I was receiving

Comment: @M_2210 if an answer solved your problem you should accept it to indicate so. Glad i could help!

Answer (score 0):

Names_of_Shapefiles is an int.  change that to a list and add what you want appended into the append call.

Also, when adding questions, note what errors you get for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
folderpath = "C:\Users\Michaelf\Desktop\GEOG M173\LabData"
filelist = os.listdir(folderpath)

print filelist

Counter_Shapefiles = 0
Name_of_Shapefiles = []

for the_file_name in filelist:
    File_Extension = the_file_name[-4:]
    if File_Extension == ".shp":
        Counter_Shapefiles = Counter_Shapefiles+1
        Names_of_Shapefiles.append(the_file_name)
```

Have a look at the changes that I've made to your code.

- For if statements you don't want your condition to be in quotation marks, as that turns it into a string. If you want to make it clear that it's your statement then you can use brackets, but it's not necessary
- In that same if statement you type file_Extension without a capital f, which isn't the same as File_Extension, so your if statement doesn't know what it's looking for.
- For your ".shp" string, that does need to be in quotation marks, to make it clear that it's a string.
- When defining your Names_of_Shapefiles array, you need to put it in square brackets, or it'll automatically become a number instead of an array.
- The .append is a function, and takes input; how else would your program know what to append to the Names_of_Shapefiles array? This is why you put what you want appending inside the brackets at the end.